# Open current command in text editor

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

A few years ago I found a command or a shortcut, I don't remember what it was but it basically opened the current command in the terminal in a text editor like vim or nano and allowed you to edit it there (with multiple lines) and then save the buffer and execute whatever you wrote in the editor.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key combination you're looking for is <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>. It's listed in output of `bind -p`:

```
$ bind -p | grep edit
"\C-x\C-e": edit-and-execute-command
```